# How to patch a gem to work properly in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to use a particular gem that hasn't been updated since the inception of Rails 3. It makes a reference to `RAILS_ROOT` when the gem is initialized, which gives me this:

```
can't convert #<Class:0x1018695c8> into String (TypeError)
```

From my understanding, this is because Rails 3 doesn't set `Rails.root` at this stage of the initialization process. Is there a way I can patch this gem, or add something somewhere to fix this issue?

Comment: Which gem are you having issues with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what I could find from a quick search, it looks like the way to go is to create a Rails::Railtie for it

see José Valim's comment here:

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4016-railsroot-returns-nil-before-app-initialization-silently-breaking-some-gems